# How to intersect shapefile with polygons in R properly?

Tags: r, sp, rgdal, rgeos

I have a WI shapefile (https://data-wi-dnr.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/wi-dnr::wisconsin-state-boundary-24k/explore?location=44.747223%2C-89.836300%2C8.20) and a grid that I want to intersect so that I can tell how many grid cells are left in the state, and give them attributes, such as an ID, etc.

```
library(sf)
library(terra)
# not needed here: library(tidyverse)
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)

wi_shape <- readOGR('C:\\Users\\ruben\\Downloads\\Wisconsin_State_Boundary_24K\\Wisconsin_State_Boundary_24K.shp')
wi_shape_projected = spTransform(wi_shape, CRS("+init=epsg:3085"))

cs <- c(1609.344, 1609.3444)*20
grdpts <- makegrid(wi_shape, cellsize = cs)
spgrd <- SpatialPoints(grdpts, proj4string = CRS(proj4string(wi_shape_projected)))
spgrdWithin <- SpatialPixels(spgrd)
spgrdWithin_poly <- as(spgrdWithin, "SpatialPolygons")
```

The problem (from what I can tell) is that I am trying to intersect a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` (`WI_shape_projected`) with a `SpatialPolygons`(`spgrdWithin_poly`) object, but I can't get the `SpatialPolygons` object into a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`.  How do I transform `spgrdWithin_poly` to the correct object type?

Comment: You've not actually said what the problem is. Is there an error message, or no error and unexpectedly wrong output? Edit the Q and describe the problem a bit!

Comment: I think you are messing up your projections. `grdpts` is created from the coordinates of `wi_shape` but then the next line gives it the CRS of `wi_shape_projected`, which it isn't. It should be assigned the CRS of `wi_shape`, and then transformed to the CRS of `wi_shape_projected`. Also, can you show the function that tries to do the intersection?

Comment: This might sound provocative, but why did you decide to continue with `sp` again, when the answers to your previous question regarding this on SO (c.f. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74828350/11709296)) suggested the use of `sf` and/or `terra`? Attribute assignment is already covered there. What is left are intersections, but you can accomplish this quite easily using `sf::st_intersection()`.